# Wearing an underware or not - which makes the hypersensitivity on your glans gone faster?

Tags: penis, clothes

For an adult male who got an operation on a phimotic penis, the hypersensitivity on the glans would keep tormenting him for a while.

But after you finish the period of putting a bandage on your penis, will having your penis outside to expose it to the air make it faster to have your penis less sensitive to an stimulation, than keeping wearing an underware? If you want to get accustomed to the hypersensitivity on your glans faster, which is the better way?